# Google Apps Script - Send email as user submitting form data

Tags: google-apps-script

Using Google Apps for business, I have a form that company users access on a google site.  The users completes the form and submits.  onSubmit, a script runs, collects the data and puts into a PDF and sends an email to me for review.

Right now when the email is sent, it comes to my inbox as me sending to me.  I'd like to have it send as the user submitting the form.  Can anyone point me in the direction to send as the user submitting the form.

permissions are set as followed:

The spreadsheet sharing option has anyone at company can find / view.
It's deployed as "execute the apps as:" User accessing the web app.  And anyone at the company can access the app.

thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the form with an HtmlService or UiApp version that runs as the user, and then the email will come from them.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your are using Google Forms, I don't believe the function/script being run onSubmit is being run by the user who fills out the form, its being run by the owner of the script (you).  As @Corey G stated, you can use HtmlService or UIApp to create a form, but takes much more time to create the form itself.

Comment: And also handling uploaded files that had been attached within the form is rather cumbersome.